# What are the claimed advantages of using Carbon fiber for a pressure hull?

Tags: pressure-vessel, carbon-fiber

Much of the news around the Titan incident has focused on all the reasons that carbon fiber was a bad choice for the hull, but I've yet to see any discussion as to *why it was chosen at all.*

Was it chosen because the designers perceived there to be some advantages in cost, construction, operation, etc. in using carbon fiber as compared to, for example, steel? (If there are, I'm not seeing them, but I'm no expert in that field, nor have I seen any reports of those being cited as the reason.) *Did OceanGate ever speak of their motivation for that choice?* Or was it motivated by some other consideration like a solution looking for a problem, "carbon fiber cool!" market differentiation or "I can't patent something that was invented over 100 years ago"?

Comment: A lot of data and opinion being collected here. Commenters include design engineers of deep submersibles. Biggest cost is the support vessel. Lighter submersible means cheaper support vessel. https://www.boatdesign.net/threads/why-did-the-titanic-tour-submarine-implode.68175/page-8#post-948312

Comment: Having said that, there is a lot of hours of old pre-accident video on the development and manufacturing of these subs. There are plenty of news articles and promo pieces in composite technology magazines. How much of this did you wade through? We expect you to do a modicum of your own research before asking here.

Comment: @PhilSweet Saving on the side of the support ship!? I'd say "that seems like an excuse for the solution that was already chose", but I've personalty seen worse false economies. And I've seen myself get too fixated on my first solution from time to time. (What's the going rate for an bigger ocean going barge?)

Comment: @PhilSweet I haven't dug very deeply, but I've skimmed more than a little both in the popular press and some of the more technical stuff. The answer to the question I'm asking seems like the kind of thing that would be prominent, even in the popular press, as it would make good headlines. If it's a cost saving thing "company founder dies in cheap sub" would sell copy, so why isn't that being reported?

Comment: Certainly a story I've heard -- both in the press, from a guy I know who does a lot of automotive carbon fiber, and from my own family business's experience with fiberglass -- is that fiber/resin composite construction doesn't perform well in compression.  Carbon fiber may be a great thing for a pressurized vessel, but for a vessel under compression (i.e., a sub) it's going to be less than optimal.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this was a decision taken by a company and we can only  guess their reasons.

Comment: The main motivation probably comes down to weight.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Of course, but it's a submersible so you'd think the weight would be fixed at whatever the weight of the displaced water is.

Comment: This video might be interesting, maybe you already watched it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LcGrLnzYuU